# How to add RTL support in PreferenceScreen on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I want to use **`PreferenceScreen`** in my setting, but i can't set `RTL` to this XML file. i've tried with this code, but it doesn't work!

`android:supportsRtl="true"` in `Manifest`

***minSdkVersion 15.***

**My XML Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/action_settings">
        <Preference
            android:key="prefDeleteAll"
            android:summary="@string/settings_delete_all_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_delete_all" />
        <Preference
            android:key="prefCustomPath"
            android:title="@string/settings_custom_path" />
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/filenameEntries"
            android:entryValues="@array/filenameValues"
            android:key="prefCustomFilename"
            android:title="@string/settings_custom_filename" />
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/sortEntries"
            android:entryValues="@array/sortValues"
            android:key="prefSortMode"
            android:title="@string/settings_sort_mode" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_customizations">
        <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
            android:defaultValue="@color/primary"
            android:key="prefPrimaryColor"
            android:summary="@string/settings_primary_color_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_primary_color" />
        <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
            android:defaultValue="@color/fab"
            android:key="prefFABColor"
            android:summary="@string/settings_fab_color_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_fab_color" />
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefNavigationBlack"
            android:summary="@string/settings_navigation_black_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_navigation_black" />
        <Preference
            android:key="prefDefaultValues"
            android:summary="@string/settings_default_customization_description"
            android:title="@string/settings_default_customization" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/action_about">
        <Preference
            android:key="prefLicense"
            android:title="@string/settings_license" />
        <Preference
            android:key="prefVersion"
            android:summary="@string/settings_about"
            android:title="@string/app_name" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I override the `Preference#onCreateView(ViewGroup)` and applied some RTL rules to the `View` returned from `super`.

Here's an implementation of a `EditTextPreferenceRTL` which behaves like an `EditTextPreference` but its 'title' and 'summary' are being displayed from **R**ight-**T**o-**L**eft:

```
public class EditTextPreferenceRTL extends EditTextPreference {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    EditTextPreferenceRTL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                          int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    EditTextPreferenceRTL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    EditTextPreferenceRTL(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    EditTextPreferenceRTL(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {

        final View view = super.onCreateView(parent);

        final int titleIndex = 0;
        final int summaryIndex = 1;

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) ((LinearLayout) view).getChildAt(summaryIndex);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpTitle = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpSummary = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getLayoutParams());

        lpTitle.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        lpSummary.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(titleIndex);
        tvTitle.setLayoutParams(lpTitle);

        lpSummary.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, tvTitle.getId());

        TextView tvSummary = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(summaryIndex);
        tvSummary.setLayoutParams(lpSummary);

        return view;
    }
}
```

---

### NOTE

This code is not forward-compatible and might break in future versions, in which there's a chance of a change in `EditTextPreference` from which `EditTextPreferenceRTL` `extends`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code with AppCompatPreferenceActivity:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
     getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick how to do it, because basiclly PreferenceScreen dont support RTL.

The easiest way to do it is to put the next code in the onCreate of your PreferenceActivity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        getListView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE);
```

That's should do the trick

Comment: You can show me the PreferenceActivity activity code?

Comment: download my codes with this link : http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04155748001618953096 . tnx please help me

Comment: You've tried to add the code I gave you after the "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" and before the "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);"?

Comment: yes,         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
            getListView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE);
        
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings); . but dose not work :( . i rally need this

Comment: If settings language dynamically this worked for me: getListView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);